# Two DropDownList and EntityFramework

Tags: drop-down-menu, entity-framework-4

I need to create the methods (or another that you recommended I) so as to filter the data in two dropdownlist. The scenario I have is as follows:

> 1) Business Class for database access (CRUD)
>
> 2) Two DropDownList (inside a GridView)

The first presents the Groups Article while the second items, according to the choice made in the first the second is populated.

The database tables consist of the following:

> 1) Table Groups
>
> 2) Table of Related Items

The reports of the tables are one-to-many, or one group can have many articles, both have their own primary key.

What suggestions do you give me?

Thank you all,

Ricardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you just need two methods:

```
- GetAllGroups(): That call Entity framework to get all groups from db
- GetArticlesByGroupID(<<groupID>>): that get articles from db based on what groups was chosen
```

the main flow of your program will be:

```
- after form is initialized, you can method GetAllGroups() and populate into first dropdownlist

- in event selected changed of first dropdownlist and call method GetArticleByGroupID(...) and populate into second dropdownlist
```

that all.

from Entity Framework view: you need to create any needed Object or DTO, such as groupDTO, ArticleDTO, GroupRespository... or something like that
hope can help you